# Resetting Highcharts to initial state

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Creating my Highchart with preset options works fine:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

However, when I want to destroy and recreate the chart it only destroys. Even if I remove `chart.destroy();` the chart is still just completely blanked but not recreated.

```
$('#resetChart').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    chart.destroy();
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

A little stuck here on how to reset this chart.

Edit::

Inspecting the chart container shows the Pie charts is creating *something* here but doesn't seem to be retrieving the data properly. Do I need to pass in my data variable again as well even though it's set in the options?

```
series: [{
                name: name,
                data: data,
                /* changes bar size */
                pointPadding: 0,
                borderWidth: 0,
                pointWidth: 15,
                shadow: false
        }]
```

Then data is defined on the page (For our CMS):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        data = [
            {
                y: {value},
                name: 'field1',
                id:'1'
            },
            {
                y: {value},
                name: 'field2',
                id:'2'
            },
            {
                y: {value},
                name: 'field3',
                id:'3'
            }
        ];
    </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#resetChart').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    while(chart.series.length > 0) chart.series[0].remove(true);
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tapkr/1

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I tried it on their basic pie demo as well: http://jsfiddle.net/tapkr/

Comment: Is that link working for you? Perhaps I'm vaving a browsers issue since the fiddle isn't resetting for me

Comment: In FF that fiddle is just destroying the chart. I do not see it being rebuilt.

Comment: Sorry Raminson, I see that this does work in the fiddle if I then call the chart again. It still won't work for my project though. I suspect it has to do with my data variable which I edited into my question.

Comment: @Grillz you should define a new chart after removing the series, have you tried this? http://jsfiddle.net/tapkr/5/

Comment: Yes, I was actually able to get this working in a fiddle, but not on my dev server, so it seems like there may be a bug with the way we're passing data. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Raminson Why don't use chart.destroy() ?

Answer (score 5):

When you create your chart for the first time you pass some options thrue the parameter, you can save them into an var and when you want to create again you use the same options like the following code.

```
var defaultOptions = {
    // your options
};

function drawDefaultChart() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(defaultOptions);
}

drawDefaultChart();

$('#resetChart').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    chart.destroy();
    drawDefaultChart();
});
```

You can see it working **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/tapkr/4/)**.